# ¿Como puedo crear una tabla en una base de datos postgres existente en Django?

Tags: base-de-datos, django, postgresql, tablas

Eso pues, estoy tratando de agregarle una tabla a una base de datos postgres ya existente en Django para que no me salga el error "no existe la relacion X" pero no encuentro la forma de hacerlo, ya probe creandola desde el pgAdmin y luego haciendo la migracion para que las filas se creen y nada, tambien intente usar el comando para migrar la tabla pero no me sale en el pgAdmin y sale este error: "No installed app with label X".
¿Alguien sabe hacerlo?

Answer (score 0):

Todo lo relacionado con la BD y Django se debe de ver directamente en Django, específicamente en `models.py`. Si quieres crear una tabla nueva en la BD debes agregar el siguiente código ejemplo en `models.py`:

```
class NombreTabla(models.Model):
  campo1 = models.TextField()
  campo2 = modeles.CharField()
```

Cuando modificas `models.py` debes ejecutar los comandos:

`python manage.py makemigrations`

Si no hubo ningún error ejecutas:

`python manage.py migrate`

Si no sale ningún error, tu tabla se creó correctamente en la BD.
Recomiendo revisar en el `admin` de Django agregando el modelo en `admin.py` de esa aplicación:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import NombreTabla

admin.site.register(NombreTabla)
```

De esta manera puedes ir a `localhost:8000/admin` (previamente debes crear un superusuario desde la terminal con `python manage.py createsuperuser`) así podrás ver si en realidad esta la tabla creada en Django.

Comment: Eso hago, pero en el pgAdmin no sale la tabla que he creado, cuando ejecuto el primer comando me sale "no changes detected" y cuando ejecuto el segundo me dice "no migrations to apply"

Comment: ¿Verificaste que los datos de la BD están correctos en `settings.py`?

Comment: si, todo esta bien

Comment: Lo único que se me ocurre es que existieran migraciones "atascadas", verifica en la carpeta `migrations` de la aplicación en la que modificaste `models.py`, puedes borrar las últimas migraciones hasta la última que sí migró, si usas VS Code te aparecen en otro color las migraciones que aún no se realizan, una vez borradas volver a hacer las migraciones.